# PHP - Copy image to my server direct from URL

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [save image from php url using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php)

I want to have PHP code for following.

Suppose I have one image URL, for example, http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png

If I run one script, this image will be copied and put on my server within folder having 777 rights.

Is it possible? If yea, can you please give direction for same?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http

Answer (score 156):

Two ways, if you're using PHP5 (or higher)

```
copy('http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png', '/tmp/file.png');
```

If not, use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

```
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/image.png", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http)

Comment: Many thanks! `copy()` did the trick

Comment: instead of the url, can it be done with bitmap image?

Comment: none is working for me.. i am trying to make it in codeignitier.. but nothing happening.. :(

Comment: Thanks Dotty,
Your Code helps me a lot.

Comment: this solution worked like a charm!... thanks!

Comment: Here, If you compare this answer with Michael Robinson's answer. This answer is quite easy. Great

Comment: In this example, the file extension of the source and destination files are different. Will the file be converted from png to jpg?

Comment: @RouthMedia I'm assuming that was a mistake.  This seems like it just makes a dumb copy and so switching extensions in the process would cause errors on read.

Answer (score 33):

From [Copy images from url to server, delete all images after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002232/copy-images-from-url-to-server-delete-all-images-after)

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); //check here         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 

$imgurl = 'http://www.foodtest.ru/images/big_img/sausage_3.jpg'; 
$imagename= basename($imgurl);
if(file_exists('./tmp/'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents('tmp/'.$imagename,$image);
```

Comment: Thanks.. This one only worked properly.. Thanks Michael

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

```
$url="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png";
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$save_path="/path/to/the/dir/and/image.jpg";
file_put_contents($save_path,$contents);
```

you must have `allow_url_fopen` set to `on`

Comment: I think you might want to clarify that the second use of $url is not the same as the first.

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. M getting this error.

Answer (score 9):

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php) will solve your problem. Solution in short:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png';
$img = '/my/folder/my_image.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = "http://www.example/images/image.gif";
$save_name = "image.gif";
$save_directory = "/var/www/example/downloads/";

if(is_writable($save_directory)) {
    file_put_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
} else {
    exit("Failed to write to directory "{$save_directory}");
}
```