# copy() not working from url to folder in php

Tags: php

I am trying to copy file from a url to a folder in my system using php

```
<?php $image = "http://l.yimg.com/t/frontpage/10-facts-slideshow-080512-630-01.jpg";
if (!copy($image, "localfolder/mainPic1.png")) {
echo "FAILED";
}else{echo "DONE";}
```

it always end up with "Failed"

- All permissions are set to the localfolder
- i checked the phpinfo and found that  `allow_url_fopen =Off`

as it is a shared server i do not have any control over the php settings . please can you suggest an alternative.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Here is the solution similar to our question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `allow_url_fopen` is off and you cannot enable it, you will need to use curl to retrieve the file and save it locally.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://l.yimg.com/t/frontpage/10-facts-slideshow-080512-630-01.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$imgdata = curl_exec($ch);

// Save to disk
file_put_contents("localfolder/mainPic1.png", $imgdata);
```

Comment: ok, i am aware of Curl and fairly know how to use it, i think even using curl i can only fetch the url's of the images? and again i will be back to where i started of copying from url again? please correct me if i am incorrect

Comment: @Jay66online Not sure what you mean by _only fetch the urls of images_. curl will fetch the image data into the returned variable.

Comment: @Jay66online I tested the code above, and it will correctly retrieve and save your image URL to a local file.

Comment: i tried the above code it works quiet good until i checked the size of the file it is saved is 0kb   :( when i did an echo '<img src="localfolder/mainPic1.png" >'; it dint show up the file that's when i checked the size

Comment: hey Michael , i just modified the contents of CURL (pasted above) and it worked !! Thanks a tonne

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `allow_url_fopen` have to `ON` for this.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Even if you are allowed to modify `php.ini` on your shared server. Create a `php.ini` and keep the value `allow_url_fopen = On` in the root folder. It generally overrides the default settings.