# save images from url through php get content

Tags: php, image, url, save

```
<?php
//Get the file
$content = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg ';
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen('/var/www/ajaxForm/loading.gif', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);


?>
```

I am getting following **error** when i try this

> Warning: fopen(/var/www/ajaxForm/loading.gif): **failed** to open
>   **stream**: No such file or directory in /var/www/curlimage.php on line 5 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /var/www/curlimage.php on line 6 Warning: fclose() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/curlimage.php on
>   line 7

Comment: Dear i have put this question here because i don't understand the error

Comment: Does Apache have good rights to create the file /var/www/ajaxForm/loading.gif ?

Comment: yes the file is already created and the apache has permissions to read and write

Comment: similar question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url

Comment: @RohitGoel Have you seen the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Just taken from [`similar question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url)

```
$url = 'http://dev.aviesta.com.mx/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/r/bridal-shoes1.jpg';
$img = 'curl/curl_image.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

**Note :** also check the directory is writable with  **[is_writable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)** method

**References :**

[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to save that image? I don't know why you write this code, you can't open a gif image and write another into it. If you want to save that image then you can use

`file_put_contents("imgfolder/imgID.jpg", $image);` or `copy($image_url, $your_path);`

Comment: this is is good but i want to save the image from the url in my local folder and it should creates the files automatically