# Copy img from url to server: no such file or directory

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

I am using php to get an image from url and copy it to my server but got an error saying there is no such file

Image example:

```
http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png
```

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url) I am using:

```
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/image.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

I am getting the following error. Did i do anything wrong?

```
fopen(/location/to/save/image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure you have permissions to create files in selected location

Comment: you can also use file_put_contents instead of fopen/fwrite/fclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function download_image($url,$destination_path = '')
{  
    // CHECKS IF CURL DOES EXISTS. SOMETIMES WEB HOSTING DISABLES FILE GET CONTENTS
    if (function_exists('curl_version'))
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

    } else
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
    }
    // CHECKS IF DIRECTORY DOESNT EXISTS AND DESTINATION PATH IS NOT EMPTY
    if(!file_exists($destination_path) && $destination_path != ''){
        mkdir($destination_path, 0755, true);  
    }
    // ATTEMPT TO CREATE THE FILE
    $fp = fopen($destination_path.'/'.date('YmdHis').".jpg", "a+");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp); 
}

download_image('http://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/jack/images/treehouse-1.png','images');
```

Comment: Saving file is the problem, not fetching the image itself :)

Comment: Validate your destination path

Comment: Actually this => `rb+` needs to be => `w` - I tried your code as is, and it didn't work. Only when I changed the `rb+` to `w`.

Answer (score 1):

---

> ## ✓ This worked for me.

---

### Try it without the `/location/to/save/`

#### The file will be saved in the same folder you run the script in.

Such as:

```
<?php

//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("image_google.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Fred , I tried your solution and it works now. However I still want to know why /location/to/save/ doesn't work

Comment: @JamesZhao You're welcome. It's because `/location/to/save/` stands to be an invalid address, unless you do have the folders `location` and sub-folders called `to` and `save` on your server, but many servers are configured that you need relative paths instead of absolute. If you wish to save to a different folder, you will need to use something to the affect of `$fp = fopen("../folder/image_google.jpg", "w");`

Comment: @JamesZhao Plus, if you feel that I have answered your question and that it is now resolved, you can click on the checkmark underneath the arrows to the left, and mark it as being "answered". Otherwise, your question will remain in the "unanswered" category, cheers.

Comment: @JamesZhao Or an `UPVOTE` would be nice. Plus, notice my comment in regards to the answer you accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243467/copy-img-from-url-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory#comment26753256_18243505

Comment: Hi Fred, I am new here. I only have 7 reputation and can't upvote your answer yet. Thank you very much for your help. Let me know if I can do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The folder (/location/to/save in here) should exist. You also need write permissions in it.

Comment: I created the folder with 0755 permission.