# Copy image to my server direct from URL and upload it to Wordpress uploads folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image through PHP script as mentioned below. I am taking image from the URL;
[I have taken reference from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url) Actually in my case I want to upload it to WordPress upload folder where post images get upload and you know WordPress creates folder on run-time inside 'wp-content/uploads/' and it uploads image there. So path ($save_path) is not decided on run time.

```
$url="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png";
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$save_path="/path/to/the/dir/and/image.jpg";
file_put_contents($save_path,$contents);
```

I am trying to use WordPress function "media_handle_upload" to upload image instead of "file_put_contents"  but I am not getting how I pass file object to this function once i get the file contents (`$contents=file_get_contents($url);`). Kindly assist.

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );
```

Comment: try this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image

Comment: or: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Comment: Wow great...Thank you so much @vrajesh 
Also plz Can you please let me know same thing for custom fields "update_field('field_568cbd913301f',$att['attach_id'],$post_id);" as i am using ACF plugin as well.

Comment: thank you so much @rnevius:

Comment: sideload . . . damn!

Answer (score 5):

100% working this code:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$imageurl = '<IMAGE URL>';
$imagetype = end(explode('/', getimagesize($imageurl)['mime']));
$uniq_name = date('dmY').''.(int) microtime(true); 
$filename = $uniq_name.'.'.$imagetype;

$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
$contents= file_get_contents($imageurl);
$savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $contents);
fclose($savefile);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => $filename,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
$imagenew = get_post( $attach_id );
$fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $imagenew->ID );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullsizepath );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data ); 

echo $attach_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete example :

```
// $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory.
$filename = '/path/to/uploads/2013/03/filename.jpg';

// The ID of the post this attachment is for.
$parent_post_id = 37;

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

// Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );
```

You can check [wp_insert_attachment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) for more info