# PHP save large parameterised image to server

Tags: php, image, curl

I have the below url of a image. It's resolution about 1500px width and 300kb.
I sent the url to server via ajax and tried to save. But it's saving half of the image. Like corrupted.

Image url:

```
$url = "https://textronic.online/WEB_API_TDS/v1/img?part=SHSLIM&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=BTBLACK&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=BHBLACK&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=BTBLACK&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=BHBLACK&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=BTBLACK&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=BHBLACK&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=BTBLACK&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=BHBLACK&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=REGULARBOTTOM&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=DIAMOND&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BOXPLEAT&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=EPNO&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BHBLACK&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BTBLACK&swatch=F1A0F99B/view=face";
```

**Method -1**

```
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$save_path="dimage.jpg";
file_put_contents($save_path,$contents);
```

**Result:** image should be red color. but it's white color. the reason is not fully saved.

---

**Method-2**

```
copy($url, 'image2.jpg');
```

**Result:** image should be red color. but it's white color. the reason is not fully saved.

---

**Method-3**
curl method. This wasn't worked. saved 0kb image.

---

**Method-4**

```
header("content-type: image/jpg");
$qr_image = imagecreatefrompng($url); 

$save = getcwd()."image4.jpg";
imagejpeg($qr_image,$save); //save the file to $save path
imagejpeg($qr_image); //display the image
```

Result is corrupted.

Basically tried the below post methods:[PHP - Copy image to my server direct from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url)

If anyone have a solution please answer here.

Thank you

Comment: 4k rep and you ask a question like this???

Comment: yes, tried 4 different methods. wasn't success.

Comment: To save an image on the server you need file upload not to send a link via ajax

Comment: @ Ferhad Othman: tried with file_get_contents, curl,copy..methods. worked only copy function. image saved but half. tried with small image and worked well with copy function without uploading the image.

Comment: @apokryfos: Tried code added for your down vote.

Comment: Retracted my downvote

Comment: Ok don't want to point out the obvious but you're getting a PNG but saving it as a JPG without properly converting it from PNG to JPG. I have ran `echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($url))."' />";` and it's showing just fine

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was my typing mistake. Code rectified. image is  jpg and need to be save as jpg.

Answer (score 2):

honestly just looks like a bug with the server. also note that the server uses http/2, so it's probably not very well-tested code. in any case, i can reproduce this problem in curl in approximately 2/10 attempts, the target server just randomly close the connection before the `content-length:` number of bytes are read, sometimes. i ran this command 10 times

```
curl -v 'https://textronic.online/WEB_API_TDS/v1/img?part=SHSLIM&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=BTBLACK&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=BHBLACK&pair=9038004B&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=9038004B/part=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=BTBLACK&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=BHBLACK&pair=EA8BD88C&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=EA8BD88C/part=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=BTBLACK&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=BHBLACK&pair=E339C530&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=E339C530/part=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=BTBLACK&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=BHBLACK&pair=B5CB81BC&swatch=F1A0F99B&pair=B5CB81BC/part=REGULARBOTTOM&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=7FEA98C3&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=DIAMOND&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BOXPLEAT&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=EPNO&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BHBLACK&swatch=F1A0F99B/part=BTBLACK&swatch=F1A0F99B/view=face'
```

and in 2/10 attempts, curl complained that the connection was closed prematurely... contact the `textronic.online` devs and let them know, they seemingly have problems with their http/2 server code. and until they fix it, use

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);` with curl to force download it with http/1.1, not http/2 - this is the equivalent of adding --http1.1 to the curl command line, which seemingly made the download stable.

(ps, no idea why so many people downvoted you, maybe the bad parts were edited away?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both servers are https. Also when I try to save the canvas image to jpg using canvas.toDataURL it shows error "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.". added cross access code to htaacess fille and not worked. bot above your answer is also telling some server issue. I guess that might be a problem in our server. Thank you hanshenrik. voted.