# How to cURL image-type projected image?

Tags: php, image, curl, jpeg, content-type

I have this problem.

There is a Joomla site that has a image presented via PHP file image.php that has some Content-Type to be projected as Image.

I want to get that image with cURL or file_get_contents and save it as .jpg file.

The URL Looks like: http://radioglos.pl/components/com_eventgallery/helpers/image.php?option=com_eventgallery&mode=full&view=resizeimage&folder=2020-12-12kielpino&file=_ZBG5132.jpg

It has image.php script that is projecting the passed image via GET parameter as Content-Type Image.

I've already tried standard file_get_contents() method aswell as all cURL methods described in this topic: [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)

Looking for answers.

Comment: Welcome. What is your question? Does something not work? Where's _your_ code? The link you posted has two ways of doing it, don't they work too?

Comment: Requesting the image data from the given URL works absolutely fine for me with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Hey. Thank you @CBroe. Probably becouse I am using php 5.4.45. Gonna investigate that. Thanks for leading me to this place.

Comment: Why are you still using such a _massively_ outdated PHP version? That has not gotten even any security fixes for ages.

Comment: Thats our client choice. Fact is that it wasnt becouse of PHP Version. It was the hidden &amp; in the link. Here's the solution: str_replace('&amp;', '&', $imgReplaced);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use file_put_contents() function

```
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/image.png", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

from
[PHP - Copy image to my server direct from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306935/php-copy-image-to-my-server-direct-from-url/6306995)

Comment: Hey. I described in the topic that I've already tried this method. 
The url is like: 
http://radioglos.pl/components/com_eventgallery/helpers/image.php?option=com_eventgallery&mode=full&view=resizeimage&folder=2020-12-12kielpino&file=_ZBG5132.jpg. Pay attention to the "image.php" detail. Its not working towards this url.

Comment: Still looking for answers. Edited topic description to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
$imgReplaced = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $imgReplaced);
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27842591)

Comment: @Devator The OP has posted a solution to the question. Solutions should not be added to the question.